# Replace column value (xml records) for one million records

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a 'Customer' table with almost 1.2million records in which one column 'customer_records' of type ntext , which contains xml data. I need to replace a url value in all existing records of the column. I have tried with below replace query but it is taking around 20 minutes of time to execute the query.

```
Update  Customer
SET  Customer_records = Cast(Replace(Cast( Customer_records As nvarchar(max)), 
N'http://testuser.testcompany.net', N'https://replaceurl.testcompany.net') As ntext)
```

The CPU consumption is utilized to the maximum during the update which is causing the concern.
Out of 1.2 million records actual updated records are 600 thousand records, but query needs to read every records to find and replace the url text.

Please in any way this can be performed more effectively using the 'Replace'.

Comment: *"of type ntext , which contains xml data"* Why are you *still* using `ntext`, it's been deprecated for **16 years**? And if it contains XML data, why are you not using the `xml` data type?

Comment: As for the problem, there is no quick solution. SQL Server is having to retrieve the blob data, convert it, scan the *entire* value, convert it back, and then store it back again as a blob, *and* it's got to do that for 1.2M values(?); that's a lot of work.

Comment: Write a powershell/exe/whatever that executes a query on the table _SELECT Field FROM TABLE_ and **on your PC** update the column.

Comment: How is that going to help the OP `UPDATE` their data in the database, @Max ?

Comment: On your script: _SELECT FIELD FROM TABLE; foreach(row in queryResult) var t = row.Field.replace(x,y); UPDATE TABLE Set Field = t WHERE ID =row.Id_

Comment: So in addition to doing the actual work required, you suggest to pull *all the data* over a network, process it RBAR on a separate machine, then push *all the data* back again? That's how I would make the process as slow as possible.

Answer (score -1):

Try Python and pandas dataframe. Or run the update with 'WITH (TABLOCK)' option.